# How to upload big Unreal Engine 4 projects to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, push, unreal-engine4, git-lfs

I am trying to publish a local repo to my GitHub repo, but I get this error message:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It is a big Unreal project using Git LFS.

I purchased a $5 50GB pack to store my LFS date.

I please see my issue [here](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/10573#issuecomment-692084931).

To my best understanding my commit is too big so GitHub can't take it.

To break up the size of my commit, so git can handle it...

I tried several commands, to no avail.

Attempt 1:

```
Nemesis03@Janek MINGW64 /g/UE4EngineBuilds/DQSWankOMate-Backup (master)
$ git repack --max-pack-size=100M -a -d
Enumerating objects: 4354, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4354/4354), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4276/4276), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4354/4354), done.
Total 4354 (delta 208), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.
```

Attempt 2:

```
Nemesis03@Janek MINGW64 /g/UE4EngineBuilds/DQSWankOMate-Backup (master)
$ git push origin master
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1786/1786), 4.7 GB | 0 B/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 4354, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4354/4354), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4068/4068), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (4354/4354), 4.00 GiB | 6.10 MiB/s, done.
Total 4354 (delta 263), reused 4299 (delta 208), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Attempt 3:

```
Nemesis03@Janek MINGW64 /g/somepath/myproject (master)
$ git push origin buchofnumbers2a7dfa56d91ed7e2a777b5c80fdb16abe915:master
error: The destination you provided is not a full refname (i.e.,
starting with "refs/"). We tried to guess what you meant by:

- Looking for a ref that matches 'master' on the remote side.
- Checking if the <src> being pushed (buchofnumbers2a7dfa56d91ed7e2a777b5c80fdb16abe915')
  is a ref in "refs/{heads,tags}/". If so we add a corresponding
  refs/{heads,tags}/ prefix on the remote side.

Neither worked, so we gave up. You must fully qualify the ref.
hint: The <src> part of the refspec is a commit object.
hint: Did you mean to create a new branch by pushing to
hint: 'buchofnumbers2a7dfa56d91ed7e2a777b5c80fdb16abe915:refs/heads/master'?
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/formatc2013/myproject.git'
```

Attempt 4:

```
$  git push origin bunchofnums2fc40a8da2dedf:refs/heads/master
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1961/1961), 5.0 GB | 1.1 MB/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 5022, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5022/5022), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4727/4727), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (5022/5022), 4.00 GiB | 6.20 MiB/s, done.
Total 5022 (delta 641), reused 4264 (delta 208), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

EDIT:
Tried adding .pak .pch .ipch and more files to lfs:

`git lfs track *.pak` etc...

That did not reduce my commit size, though. I mean this line still says 4GBs...

```
Writing objects: 100% (5022/5022), 4.00 GiB | 6.20 MiB/s, done.
```

I guess I got to get that number down to 2 gigs somehow...

I had a look at my local repo, and most of the heavy stuff is in the Intermediate folder, but AFAIK that's something you don't delete...

Comment: Does the problematic commit have one large file, or several files that collectively are too large?

Comment: I have to double check, but I think more than one!

Comment: I found a [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files) from GitHub where they describe how to working with large files. And I found a nice [blog post](https://medium.com/@AyunasCode/how-to-push-large-files-to-github-253d05cc6a09) how to push large files to GitHub with one mnemonic: "FIRST add git lfs track, THEN add a large file (like audio, etc.) to your repo."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into this problem all of the time, and here is my (probably terrible) workaround:

Overview: My method is to create a duplicate of the project and then slowly migrate the assets over a bit at a time. The reason is that either github or github desktop doesn't like to push 1 GB of data at one time. If you add any content more than 1 GB of data, then github will just keep failing to push.

Step 1: Make a duplicate of [project_name] and call it [project_name]_copy

Step 2: Delete all of the new content from [project_name].

Step 3: Transfer 0.9 GB of content from [project_name]_copy over to [project_name].

Step 4: Commit and push.

Repeat steps 3 & 4 until you've caught up.

If anyone knows a better way, I'd love to  hear it!